# Preventing refresh on reactive form Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular 2 application. On my sign-up page I have a billing and shipping address. On load (ngOninit) the shipping form is hidden, shipping address will only show if a checkbox is pressed and copies (setValue) values from the billing. this indicates that our customer wants a different address.

So from here the shipping address is opened/shown and checkbox is unchecked. Now the weird thing for me is that when user input is invalid let's say an email and tries to submit, it refreshes the form and copies the value from billing, customer now will re-enter the shipping address again.

here's snippet ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.checkBoxDynamicValidator();
  }

onSubmit(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

/**
   * this function sets up the validation for the shipping address
   * validation is controlled by the checkbox
   */
  private checkBoxDynamicValidator(): void {
    const changesCheckBox$ = this.companySignUpForm.get('checkBoxBilling')
      .valueChanges;
    const shipAddressAttrCtrl = this.companySignUpForm.get(
      'ship_address_attributes'
    ) as FormGroup;
    changesCheckBox$.subscribe((valOfCheckBox) => {
      this.populateShippingAddress(valOfCheckBox);
      if (valOfCheckBox) {
        this.clearCustomValidators(shipAddressAttrCtrl);
      } else {
        this.setCustomValidators(shipAddressAttrCtrl);
      }
    });
  }

/**
   * populate shipping address if checkbox "same as billing" is unchecked
   */
  private populateShippingAddress(isChecked: boolean): void {
    const shipAddGroup = this.companySignUpForm.get('ship_address_attributes');
    const billAddGroup = this.companySignUpForm.get('bill_address_attributes');
    // TODO: move to a helpers
    const selectedCountry = this.countries.find( country => Number(country.id) === Number(billAddGroup.value.country_id));
    this.setShippingState(selectedCountry.states);
    if (!isChecked) {
      shipAddGroup.setValue({
        firstname: billAddGroup.value.firstname,
        lastname: billAddGroup.value.lastname,
        address1: billAddGroup.value.address1,
        address2: billAddGroup.value.address2,
        city: billAddGroup.value.city,
        zipcode: billAddGroup.value.zipcode,
        phone: billAddGroup.value.phone,
        country_id: billAddGroup.value.country_id,
        state_id: billAddGroup.value.state_id
      });
    }
  }
```

`changesCheckBox$.subscribe((valOfCheckBox) => {}` this code fires every time the page has error or after submitting an invalid form, even though checked box is not pressed or change. Can I do prevent default here? I did a prevent default onSubmit nothing works.

html snippet:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="companySignUpForm">
   ... html here

   <button[disabled]="companySignUpForm.pristine ||companySignUpForm.invalid ||companySignUpForm.get('billingType').value !== 'creditCard'"
              (click)="onSubmit($event)">
        {{ 'register' | translate }}
   </button>
</form>
```

Any idea? I felt like this is a bug or something. I'm not sure though but this is a weird behavior. I know that the `valueChanges` form Abstract Control but I'm not actually pressing or clicking the checkbox though. It's really weird.

Incidentally, the form is being "refreshed" not the page.

Comment: I use to control that scenario outside the form control using a property(getter and setter) binded to the **ngModel of your checkbox**. On setter function call the **form.control.setValue** and **populeShippingAddress**.

Comment: @LeonardoNeninger hello my guy. I think did the same thing too. Ill post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I did. Upon observing I just realized that the checkbox technically is not part of the form. It's just a toggle button to hide and show, that's why there was a cleanup before submitting we're deleting the `checkbillingvalue` property so what I was.

Change the input to this:

```
<input
 type="checkbox"
 id="test-checkbox"
 class="p-0 mr-3"
 [checked]="checkBoxValue"
 (change)="onCheckBoxEvent($event)"
 />
```

and did the same logic inside the `onCheckBoxEven` method. This is a refactor from my previous work. I thought that every `input` or tag that is associated to the form you need to add formcontrol.